# Cassandra datastax cpp driver - avoiding unnecessary copies

Tags: c++, cassandra

I've been using the following pattern to construct my insert statements to Cassandra (using the datastax cpp driver):

```
ssStmt1 << "Insert Into some table (...) Values (....)"
string          sStatement1     = ssStmt1.str();
CassString      cass1           = cass_string_init(sStatement1.c_str());
CassStatement*  pStmt1          = cass_statement_new(cass1, 0);
```

I've tried the following pattern also:

```
CassString      cass1   = cass_string_init("Insert Into some table (id, date, c ) Values (?, ?, ?);");
CassStatement*  pStmt1  = cass_statement_new(cass1, 3);

cass_statement_bind_uuid  ( pStmt1, 0, uuidKey);
cass_statement_bind_int64 ( pStmt1, 1, timestamp);
cass_statement_bind_string( pStmt1, 2, sSomething);
```

The first pattern works with compound keys, the second doesn't.  The key consists of a timestamp and a uuid.

The timestamp field has one of two errors (depending on the bind statement used).

When bound like this:

```
cass_statement_bind_int64_by_name ( pStmt1, "date", timestamp);
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid null value for clustering key part.
```

When bound this way:

```
cass_statement_bind_int64 ( pStmt1, 1, timestamp);
```

I get the following error:

```
Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (19)
```

The first pattern above writes the data to a stringstream.  It's then copied to an std::string, before being copied to a CassString, e.g. it's very inefficient; not good when the purpose of using Cassandra was for high transaction rates.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting these errors when attempting to bind the int64 to a timestamp field?

(timestamps are stored in cassandra as int64's - the num of milliseconds since the epoch.  The cassandra.h file says that they're bound as int64's)

https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/9b0c5c/include/cassandra.h
(search for timestamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd need more information to determine why you're getting this error:

> Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (19)

Are you able to share your code?

The following error is a result of trying to use a "by_name" method on a non-prepared statement:

> Invalid null value for clustering key part.

To bind a value by name requires the metadata returned by preparing a statement.  Reference: https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/1.0/include/cassandra.h#L1021-L1022 Also, make sure to check the result of `cass_statement_bind_int64_by_name()`.

I've created an example that uses both a composite key and a compound partition key:
https://gist.github.com/mpenick/ba44e24300609994ecb4

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: thanks for this; I'll have a look over your example later today and respond.